# Small remote network fileserver access

Tags: networking, ip, filesystems, network-share, subnet

I need to connect 4 separate offices to the same file server remotely. To achieve this the offices will be connected over the internet with BT ADSL using LAN to LAN VPN routers with the following IP
configuration

Location 1
Router internal IP Address 192.168.20.254
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0

Location 2
Router internal IP Address 192.168.21.254
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255

Location 3
Router internal IP Address 192.168.21.254
Subnet Mask 255.255.0.0

Location 4
Router internal IP Address 193.208.22.254
Subnet Mask 255.0.0.0

I have been told VPN connections wont work? is this correct or is it something to do with the IP's/subnets that are incorrect? why would this not work? what kind of routers would I need?

Thanks 
Scott

Comment: You'll need to provide details of your VPN routers - what brand and model are they - before you can get any kind of answer.  I can tell you right now that Location 2 won't work unless you are doing a bunch of other things - that subnet mask doesn't allow any other hosts in the same subnet.  And Location 4 doesn't look like a valid private address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am using http://www.lambda-tek.com/CISCO887VA-SEC-K9-CISCO-887-VDSL-ADSL-OVER-POTS-MULTI-MODE-ROUTER-W-ADV-IP-EN~cs/B512476
Do all locations need to be on the same subnet or should they be on different ones as they are now?  i will revise the IPs, what would stop location 2 from working?

Comment: The subnet only allows for one host on the network, so how are you going to have any clients which are using this router?  I think you need to brush up on your networking or get paid for help with this task.

Comment: Have you made a mistake and the mask at each subnet should be 255.255.255.0?

Answer (score 1):

Your subnet masks on site 3 means its network oberlaps with the network at sites 1 and 2.

Site 4 also overlaps with all other sites.

if possible i would set each site to use a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

if this is not possible then you can either re-ip your site, or use some IP masqerade on the VPN.

If this cannot be done then put the fileserver in its own I.P. space that is different to all four lans